# error: "Some projects cannot be imported because they already exist in the workspace" when i tried to import SWT to Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I import SWT to my project in Java (I work with Eclipse), but I did a mistake and import a version of 64 bit and my JVM is 32-bit. 
So I tried to import the version of 32-bit but I got an error

> "Some projects cannot be imported because they already exist in the workspace"

In eclipse I select

> Import -> Existing Projects into Workspace -> Select archive file

and choose the correct file of 32-bit.

Then i did a big mistake and erased the folder "org.eclipse.swt" from my workspace, because I thought I will be able to import the 32-bit version.

But now I don't have also the 64-bit (I get errors like "org.eclipse.swt does not exist" etc)

Does anyone know what I should do???

Comment: I would just create a new workspace and start again with the right files

Answer (score 11):

Try this

Uncheck the "copy projects into workspace" checkbox, and then click "refresh" button.

Comment: This was the only approach that worked with Eclipse Kepler.  The other dupes should point to here.   Thanks.